# I want to get all the workitems related to a particular release from rally in C#

Tags: rally

We are working on a project to create reports from rally. I like to get all the workitems under a particular release and for that I tried to give release.name equals R.. but still it is getting all the work items. Could you please guide me with source code.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example showing the problem, with some example data?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is grab the _ref pointer that points to the work items associated with a particular release.  This _ref pointer is retrieved when you query a given release for its "TypeDefinitions" field.

```
        RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi();
        restApi.Authenticate("UserName", "PassWord", "ServerURL", proxy: null, allowSSO: false);

        Request request = new Request("release");
        request.Fetch = new List<string>() { "Name", "Description", "FormattedID", "TypeDefinitions" };
        request.Query = new Query("Name", Query.Operator.Equals, "ReleaseName");
        QueryResult queryResult = restApi.Query(request);

        var typeDefsUrl = "";
        foreach (var result in queryResult.Results)
        {
            // Get the ref that points to your work items
            typeDefsUrl = result["TypeDefinitions"]["_ref"];
        }
```

From there you can use the Request object's CreateFromUrl to create an additional request who's response will be your collection of work items.

```
        Request typeDefRequest = Request.CreateFromUrl(typeDefsUrl);
        QueryResult typeDefsResult = restApi.Query(typeDefRequest);

        foreach (var result in typeDefsResult.Results)
        {
            // Process your work items
        }
```

If you grab the latest release of the [.Net Rest Api](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitFor.NET) the [documentation](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitFor.NET/tree/master/Documentation) has been extensively updated including code examples.